# What is the C#-idiomatic way to convert a string of characters into a string of hexadecimal characters?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a string of characters, but I would like to have a string of hexdecimal characters where the hexadecimal characters are converted by turning the original characters into integers and then those integers into hexadecimal characters. How do I do that?

This is how I did it in VB:

```
for i = 1 to len(str)
    hex_str = hex_str + lcase(cstr(hex(asc(mid(str, i, 1))))) 
next
```

Now, what's the most idiomatic way to do this in C#?

Comment: please use something like http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: try with this converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @JonathanAllen, no, it is not a useless question. When asking something on SO the OP should normally provide some attempts into solving the problem. If he doesn't he shouldn't be asking here. He should probably be looking to hire a C# developer to do the job for him. SO is not an outsourcing company. So I repeat my question to the OP: What have you tried: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @JonathanAllen: I disagree.  Stack Overflow isn't a means of farming out small development tasks.  It's generally encouraged that the OP put _some_ effort into the task and point out where it's not working.  In this case it would have been as simple as trying to convert it to C# (it's reasonable to assume the OP knows _some_ C#, otherwise why is he converting anything?) and present us with any compiler/logic errors that he doesn't understand or with which he needs help.  Simply asking us to do the conversion for him is a bit presumptuous.

Comment: @msarchet If you use a converter then you won't get idiomatic C#. Instead you'll get a bunch of compatibility functions from the VB runtime.

Comment: This function is just returning the ascii integer code for each letter in your string, then converting that integer to a hexidecimal representation and concatenating those results together.

Comment: @David If he doesn't know the C# equivalent to the hex, asc, and mid functions, then he doesn't know them.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: If that's his question then it should be phrased as such.  "What do these functions do and what is the C# equivalent?" or "What is the C#-idiomatic way to do [insert task here], which this VB code does?"  As it stands, "Convert this to C# for me" is a poor question.  He should specify what it is about the code that's presenting a stumbling block for him.  From the question as-is, I can only assume the stumbling block is that he doesn't know C# syntax and doesn't want to know it.

Comment: @David: I don't see how he would have came up with my approach all by himself. Changed the question and threw in a reopen vote, sometimes it's more useful to ask your relatives...

Answer (score 4):

In C# the easiest approach I can come up with is:

```
var hexStr = str.ToCharArray()
                .Aggregate("", (current, c)
                               => current + Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString("X"));
```

This first line turns the string into a character array of type `char[]`, the second and third line convert each character into an integer `Int32` and then into a hexadecimal character of type `String`. That hexadecimal character is added to the `hexStr` of type `String` through an [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).

Here are the functions used in above expression:

- [String.ToCharArary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx)
- [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx); from System.LINQ, so you might need to add `using System.LINQ;`
- [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx)
- [Int32.ToString(String format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx), passing `"X"` makes the result hexadecimal instead of decimal.

For aggregation, I have used a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (`parameters => return value`). It's a function that takes `current` and `c` and does `return current + Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString("X");`

If something is unclear, feel free to ask in the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a VB.NET developer but with a converter, I have this :

```
for (i = 1; (i <= str.Length); i++) {
     hex_str = (hex_str + hex(asc(str.Substring((i - 1), 1))).ToString().ToLower());
}
```

Comment: I don't know what converter you used but what's `hex` and `asc`? This won't compile.

Comment: @TomWijsman They are built-in functions in VB.

Comment: It's because HEX and ASC are inbuilt functions with no analog in C# - the converter has probably just inlined those functions as they are. It's effectively taking an string, getting the integer ascii code, then returning the hex code for that integer by the looks of it.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: But not in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= str.Length; i++)
    {
        hex_str = hex_str + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(str[i - 1]), 16).ToUpper()).ToLower();
    }
```

Comment: I think there are slightly too much conversions in there. :D